# Do I have to be on a specific OS to compile for a specific OS when using Qt?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, compilation

When I was using pyqt it was necessary to compile for mac on a mac, instead of being able to export a build for mac from linux (or windows, or whatever)

Now that I'm using straight c++ development, does this fact change at all? Or must I still compile for a given OS on the given OS?

Ideally I'd love to be able to just pick a platform and compile for it. Unity3d does this, but I imagine I'm comparing apples and oranges at this point.

Is this possible? Or do I got to find a friend with a mac? Cuz I don't have no friends... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically yes, you have to. In some cases you can cross-compile, for example, this is available stock for android apps, as there is no Qt SDK that can run on android cross-compilation is the only option. You can also [build a custom Qt to cross-compil](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#cross-compilation-options)e to another OS. This is not available by default, it requires a custom build.

However, when it comes to ios or macos cross-compilation is not an option, as far as I know there is no way around but to compile under macos.

Comment: Thank you for your help.